# Open an image from an archive and load into cv2

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I'm trying to load an image from an archive into CV2.

my file statement is the archive path.

```
file = "Final/small_img.zip"
```

Next I am trying to open the archive one image at a time in a loop:

```
#import the zipfile as archive
with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as archive:
    
    #get the filename of all files in the archive and append to a list
    archive_file = archive.namelist()
    
    #Test initial program with a single image
    news = archive.open(archive_file[0])
    pic = cv.imread(news)
    #pic = Image.open(news)
```

I can open the image with PIL using Image.open(news), but as I wasn't to run both pytesseract and haarcascade, I need the image in an array.

Comment: Do you want to read the zipped images with `cv2.imread`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue, I had forgotten to import numpy....

```
#import the zipfile as archive
with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as archive:
    #get the filename of all files in the archive and append to a list
    archive_file = archive.namelist()

    # Test initial program with a single image
    news = archive.open(archive_file[0])
    pic = Image.open(news)
    pic_arr = np.array(pic)

    #Test tesseract
    #im1 = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(pic)
    im1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(pic)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(pic_arr)
    print(f"{len(faces)} faces detected in the image.")
```